# Combobox with checkbox items in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, checkbox, combobox

I need to create combobox containing items with checkbox. This is winform VB.NET application.

I found some options but, those are in c# and also, in separate library.

I need some simple way like some single class which allow me to create item with checkbox and iterate checked items.

can any one suggest me way ?

Thank You

Comment: what is the problem with using a library where someone has already done the work? The combo is fairly difficult to extend, in this case you have to take over how the items are rendered.

Comment: I would do what @Plutonix has mentioned, or another suggestion is to use a checkedlistbox; you can iterate through the checked items.